# SICF services in SAP

Tags: service, sap-basis

Where stored code `SICF` services in SAP ? I am interested in the path on the SAP local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the source code of the programs that handle the services enabled in SICF, take a look at the service definition, tab handlers - there are the class names that handle the request, listed in order.

Sorry, but your questions tend to be extremely short and everything but precise. This way, you'll likely get more guesswork than actual answers.